# JPA Annotations for many-to-many relation between objects of the same entity

Tags: jpa, annotations, many-to-many

I want to implement a Role Hierarchy but am rather new to JPA Annotations.

I have a Role Entity with a name and an id(implicit via `AbstractPersistable`):

```
@Entity
@Table(name="role")
public class Role extends AbstractPersistable<Long> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8127092070228048914L;  
    private String name;
```

Now I want to be able to define the following relationships:

- a Role can have many child roles
- a Role can be child to many roles

How would I do that with Hibernate annotations? Can I define this inside the Role Entity

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
@JoinTable( name = "role_hierarchy", 
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "role_id")}, 
            inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="child_role_id")})  
private List<Role> roles;

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
@JoinTable( name = "role_hierarchy", 
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "child_role_id")}, 
            inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="role_id")})  
private List<Role> children;
```

Am I on the right track? What am I missing?

Thank's a lot for your help!

---

**EDIT:** - removed as it has been solved -

---

**EDIT 2:**

Looks like I have some bug in my application stack. On the model defining level the role_hierarchy is working out just fine, so never mind EDIT 1...

BUT: Both ways seem to work (that is createing the m:n table entry, cascading delete and retrieval of parents and children for an entity):

- my proposal of defining a join column for both sides with no `mappedBy` property at the `@ManyToMany` annotation
- as well as defining an owning side and an inverse side.

What's the difference? Does it matter?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Bidirectional relationship consists of owning and inverse sides.

At the owning side you declare physical properties of the relationship:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
@JoinTable(name = "role_hierarchy", 
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "role_id")}, 
            inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="child_role_id")})  
private List<Role> roles;
```

At the inverse side you point at the corresponding owning side with `mappedBy` attribute:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, mappedBy = "roles")
private List<Role> children;
```

For many-to-many relationships it doesn't matter which side is the owning side (as long as you modify both sides consistently, since only changes at the owning side are propagated to the database).

**See also:**

- [2.2.5.3.2. Many-to-many](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html/entity.html#eentity-mapping-association-collection-manytomany)

Comment: Looks like you way works as well as mine(see edit2). Wonder what's the difference... ?

Comment: @Pete: Without `mappedBy` you create two unidirectional relationships instead of a sinlge bidirectional one. I'm not sure how would it work when two relationships use the same join table.