# Many-To-Many with only one Collections in the same entity?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

I have the following entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    ...

    private List<User> connections;

    ...

}
```

Assume there are Users *A* and *B*. User *A* decides to add  User *B* to his connections list. Connections list of *A* must contain User *B* and connection list of *B* must contain User *A*.

Considering my business logic, I have concluded that Many-To-Many relationship has to be used. I have found this question ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7513440/jpa-annotations-for-many-to-many-relation-between-objects-of-the-same-entity)) on Stackoverflow,  but this is not exactly what I was looking for. I want to store only one List in my entity class instead of two.

How can I implement this? I assume there must be two lists to create Many-To-Many relationship, so I guess my decision is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you have a table `user_users(user_1_id,user_2_id)` in your database for the many-to-many relationship between `user`s you can do something like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    private List<User> connections;

}
```

and now you can have the getConnection `getter` like this:

```
@ManyToMany(targetEntity=User.class)
@JoinTable(
    name="user_users",
    joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="user_1_id", nullable=false),
    inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="user_2_id", nullable=false)
)
public Set<ElementBean> getConnections() {
    return connections;
}
```

and you can add users to user like this:

```
public void addConnection(User usr) {
    if (usr !=null) { 
        connections.add(usr);
        usr.getConnections().add(this); 
    }    
}
```